# Using Jquery in Flask to add Input Fields

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I am trying to add extra input fields Dynamically using Jquery in Flask.

I believe my code is correct however whenever I click the 'add entry' button nothing happens. When I load the page I get these errors of 304.

```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2021 16:13:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2021 16:13:25] "GET /static/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2021 16:13:25] "GET /static/inputFields.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

I have downloaded the jquery file and placed it in the static folder with the other js code but nothing seems to work.

inputFields.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function (e){
    event.preventDefault()
    $(#'#items').append('<div><input type="text" name="user-name" ><input type="text" name="user-email"><input type="button" value="delete" id="delete" /></div>');
  });

  $('#delete').click(function (e){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

inputNum.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action ="">

<div id="items">
  <input type="text" name="user-name"><input type="text" name="user-email">
</div>
<input type="button" value="add entry" id="add">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='inputFields.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `304` is not error it means  the file is not modified! For more information visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304)

Comment: Nothing happens because there's a syntax error in your jQuery code: `$(#'#items')` please always check the browser console (especially before posting here) Note that your delete code is also broken, you aren't supposed to have multiple elements with the same id: https://jsfiddle.net/vxywmg5f/ (also, if a button doesn't exist at the time you're adding the event listener, it won't work, that's why I use jQuery event delegation by adding the click listener to the document instead)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the help :) i must have looked at the code for 2 hours without noticing the bug